# Animate DIV after changing HTML content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider

I'm trying to add animation to a DIV after changing it's HTML content. I've successfully changed the content of the div, but adding animation to the change is my problem.

This is what I've tried:

```
$('.tabs').on('click', 'div', function() {
    // Replace Div 
    $(this).toggleClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');

    // Get the clicked div id
    var tab = $(this).attr('data-id');
    var tab_obj = $("#" + tab +"").html();

    // Replace loader div with the clicked div HTML content
    $("#loader").html(tab_obj).fadeIn(500);
});
```

Here's the link to my code on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c1nfx8jr/6/

Comment: Put a [mcve] in your question please.

Comment: What animation? Moving the blue bar? You aren't saying what you want and you aren't showing what you tried.

Comment: When I click on the tabs, it's changing the image. I want those images to change with animation. @ChrisG

Comment: Thanks, I've gotten where the error is coming from. I linked the slim version of jQuery. I've just included the full version and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Just add an class on the content and animate it. (default: display none, and on .active ... fadeIn())